# Padding creates weird black line on my <ul>

Tags: html, css, list, menu, html-lists

The padding creates a weird black line when I stretch the background of the  in the CSS and the more padding I add the larger the black line gets  here's the image:

http://i61.tinypic.com/2ia7rlv.jpg

Here's the code:

CSS:

```css
/* reset browser styles */
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* end of browser styles */

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/notosanshebrew.css);

#logo {
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-top: 10px;
}

nav {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
 padding: 2px;}
nav li {
 display: inline;
 padding: 0 20px;
}
nav ul {
 list-style-type: none;
}
nav ul a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}

nav a:hover {
 color: rgb(207, 207, 207);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html dir="rtl" lang="he-IL" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SD עיצובים</title>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
   <header div="mainHeader">
    <nav div="mainNav">
     <ul>
      <img id="logo" src="images/title5.png"/>
      <li><a href="index.html">דף הבית</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">אודות</a></li>
      <li><a href="jewelery.html">תכשיטים</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">צור קשר</a></li>
     <ul>
    <nav>
   <header>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code. Instead of closing the `<nav>` with a `</nav>` you open a new one under the `<ul>` element.

Comment: Not a problem. Remember to check one of the answers to mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing closing tags in your ul, nav and header elements. The browser treat it as if you were creating new elements.

Correct code :

```
<div id="wrapper">
            <header div="mainHeader">
                <nav div="mainNav">
                    <ul>
                        <img id="logo" src="images/title5.png"/>
                        <li><a href="index.html">דף הבית</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">אודות</a></li>
                        <li><a href="jewelery.html">תכשיטים</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">צור קשר</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </div>
```

Working solution :

http://jsfiddle.net/xL5c4t6y/

Comment: Thanks, I thought that because I'm writing HTML5 code the elements close themselves. Which elements do which don't?

Comment: img, input, br, hr, meta, etc. You should always close them as best practice though

Comment: I disagree that always closing tags is best practice since it's not valid HTML 5. And OPs doctype is HTML 5, not XHTML.

Comment: of course I meant self closing tag (<img src="#" alt="e" /> ) these are perfectly valid in HTML5

Comment: No, [according to the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements) it is not valid HTML5. Run it through http://validator.w3.org/ if you don't believe me.

Comment: Thanks for noting it, I found out that according to the creator of the specs  Ian Hickson it doesn't really matter although it's not best practice to close HTML5 elements and closing them just makes the browser ignore them. Furthermore the reason some people do prefer to close HTML5 elements is to make the code compatible with XML . @jurgemaister for what reason would someone want to make his code XML compatible?

Comment: @Space_Monkey the way I see it there's never a reason to use it with HTML 5. If you need to be XML compatible, use XHTML